# Connect Visual Basic form to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2008. I have created a visual basic form that allows user to enter his details. Now I need to store the data entered by the user in the SQL database.

Can anyone tell me how to connect my form to the database. I am new to Visual Basic, so can please anyone provide me with some links regarding the same.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very nice set of tutorials [here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials) that show how to do data access with ASP.NET that you should be able to translate to Windows forms (In both VB & C#)